# What is the logic behind "<" and ">" string operators in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I wanted to sort a vector of strings in terms of their ASCII order and my first try was using `< >` operators.I got some weird results and then I found `compare` function for strings in c++ and completed my task.
But after that when I was reading [c++ reference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/), It was written that `> <` operators are using the exact `compare` function for strings! So why do I get different results like this:

```
int main(){
    cout << ("ali" > "Zahra") << endl;
    string a = "ali";
    cout << a.compare("Zahra");
}
```

the output is

```
0
461569
```

which means in the comparison with `>` operator `"ali"` comes first but with `compare` function "Zahra" comes first (which is more sensible because of ASCII).

So my question is how does these operators work for strings?

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes. It compares the strings' characters in terms of their ASCII code starting from the index 0 character

Comment: "Ali" and "Zahra" are pointers to strings. You are comparing pointers in the first case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"ali"` and `string a = "ali";` are two ways to define a string value but have different types.

`"ali"` is a string literal, which the C++ standard defines as an `array of n const char` where `n` is the length of the string up to `\0`. This is commonly seen as `const char[n]`

`string a = "ali";` type is explicitly defined with a type `string` (std::string) and the value `ali`.

So your first `cout` statement is calling `operator>` between two `const char[n]`, and in the second `cout` statement, you are calling `std::string::compare()` and passing in a value of type `const char[n]`

And thus the results of two different function calls are not the same.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that there is no specialization for `operator>(const char* lhs, const char* rhs)` which is considering the lexicographic order. So in the first case:

```
"ali" > "Zahra"
```

is done through `operator>(const void*, const void*)` which compares memory addresses, not the content of the string.

To force using the lexicographic comparison you must use at least one `std::string` argument, eg: `std::string("ali") > "Zahra`, so that the proper overload will be chosen.

Comment: Probably better to use `std::string_view` in this case.